# Google Map Api not displaying with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Im using Angular to display the users `Latitude`, `Longitude`. and `Altitude`, and then produce a google-map to show the user their location on a map. I've been able to do all of those except produce the map. I have been able to generate the map without errors, but can not get the map to visibly show.

I have read around and seen that having the width and height of the containing `div` set at a relative size prevents the map from being shown, but i have addressed that issue.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

<google-map  id="map-canvas" ng-controller="MapController as mapCtrl"></google-map>
```

### CSS

```
#map-canvas{
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
```

### map.js

```
   var app = angular.module('map', []);

    app.controller("MapController", function ($scope) {
    var map = this;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var alt = position.coords.altitude;

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };
        $scope.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            map.lng = lng;
            map.lat = lat;
            map.alt = alt;

        });
```

### Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### New HTML

```
 </div>
   <google-map ng-controller="MapController as mapCtrl"></google-map>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

By changing the `id="map-canvas"` to a seperate div instead of inside my directive, the map displays fully. Im just not sure what is not allowing my map to display inside its own directive. The controller is not even included in the seperate div, so I really dont know why the code in my app.js is able to even display the map in the div that is outside of directive that the controller is in.